# Custom Dialog Below any View(Button, imageButton etc)

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I want a custom Dialog which is open just below the View, suppose i have a button and when i click that button the custom dialog is open just below the button.Please suggest or give me any solution.Can i use Sliding Drawer for that?
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just go for this link it will help you...to create custom dialog..

http://www.londatiga.net/it/how-to-create-quickaction-dialog-in-android/

http://www.androidpatterns.com/uap_pattern/quick-actions

http://lemonbloggywog.wordpress.com/2011/01/06/custom-dialogs-within-an-activity%E2%80%93android/

http://androidforbeginner.blogspot.in/2012/09/custom-popup-window-development-in.html

[image]