# android: Onclick editText show value in alert dialog just below that specific editText

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-alertdialog

I have multiple editText in my app. I have achieved to show value of editText in alert dalog. The problem is that its shown in center of screen and sometimes cover the editText.
I want a way that the alert dialog {with no title and no button (which I have already done) and show just message} to shown below the specific editText which I click.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in Advance

> **NOTE** 
>    CHANGING GRAVITY DOESNT HELP BCOZ OF DIFFERENT SCREEN SIZES

**MY CODE**

**UNDER ON CREATE**

```
 etDesc = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etdesc);
         etDesc.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
         {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) 
                {
                if (etDesc.getText().toString().equals(("")))
                {
                    //Do nothing
                }
                else
                {
                setalert();
            }

                }

                });
```

**FUNCTION OF ALERT**

```
public void setalert()
        {
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext); 
            AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
            alert.setMessage(etDesc.getText().toString());
            alert.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);

            WindowManager.LayoutParams wmlp = alert.getWindow().getAttributes();

             wmlp.gravity = Gravity.CENTER ;
             wmlp.x = 100;   //x position
             wmlp.y = 100;   //y position

            alert.show();
        }
```

Comment: I Have tried Center | LEFT . But on different screen size it shows differently

Comment: Do you want alertdialog without title ? Please be precise what you want exactly and what is the current status?

Comment: alert.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE); use this to avoid title.

Comment: Yes without TITLE WITHOUT BUTTONS. ITS Just to show whats unside the editText. actually the EditTEXt are single line but data is multi line. so on click I want to show whats inside it

Comment: for this you can use custom dialog box and make that custom dialog box transparent.

Comment: but still it wont solve how to show the value of editText in alert just below that specific editTeXt

Comment: are you trying to implement `tooltip` like feature ?

Comment: IF there is an alternative other than toast. please tell that also

Comment: This link may help you.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14272825/custom-dialog-below-any-viewbutton-imagebutton-etc

Comment: @shree202 : I dont know what tooltip is like

Comment: yes i wan that kind of feature. @shree202

Comment: @PramodJGeorge : yeah your link is useful. I will check that out.

Comment: check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21153189/1739882

Comment: @PramodJGeorge : I think its too much coding for just a simple custom alert

Comment: Can we not just simply align alert dialog below the editText???

Comment: Is there No alternative to this???

Comment: try using popupwindow, where you can decide the position of  the window based on the view.

Comment: can u share a link explaining popup

Comment: I think following link will help you,http://android-er.blogspot.in/2012/03/example-of-using-popupwindow.html

Comment: http://mrbool.com/how-to-implement-popup-window-in-android/28285

Comment: the above link is more useful i guess

Comment: yes @tusharnarang, the link is good and informative. Hope it solves your problem. :)